# How to have multiple scr attributes in a script

Tags: javascript, html, element

we are generating some html with flask and jinja, at the end we are sourcing jquery in 2 different places in the html, one portion is been generated in the python view and passed by, the other one come from the templates,

one script element is inside the table element/tag, and the other script element is inside the body,

if the one in the body is uncommented, we get the error "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'tablesorter'" and I think is because the table with the class is above? and might be like python that the function need to exist first above so we can use it. 
because if I move it to the top of the body doesn't matter if is repeated, all works.
 is there a way to tell html to use the script with it the table everything that is inside the table?

is there like trick that you can specify the path of the script you want to use? or the element that want to be used by the library?

what happen when a website use 2 different versions of jquery or other library?

thanks guys, I appreciate the help =)

this is the example:

```
<body>
<!--if is at the top of the body also everything works-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header"> <h1>PRESENTATION</h1> </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed tablesorter" id="total_table">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.29.2/js/jquery.tablesorter.js">                    </script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                   $('#total_table')
                   .tablesorter({
                       ignoreCase: false,
                       widthFixed: true,
                       sortResetKey: 'ctrlKey',
                       headerTemplate : '{icon}{content}',
                       theme : "bootstrap",
                       }
                   )
                });
            </script>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <p>
                            my values
                        </p>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            17
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            10
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            5
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





    <!--if i comment next line website works and i can sort the table-->
    <!--but if i have it here doesnt work =(-->
    <!--how can i have it in 2 places? or tell the first one just to affect that table or div?-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>-->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("this function is working")
    });
</script>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Start by writing valid HTML. script elements are not allowed to be children of table elements. https://validator.nu/

Comment: You've got three jQuery script tags - get rid of 2 of them.  The reason you get the tablesorter error when you uncomment the final jQuery script include is because jQuery is included, then tablesorter runs and instantiates itself as a jQuery plugin, and then you include jQuery again which wipes the plugin cache and starts again.  So, when anything tries to use tablesorter it doesn't know what it is.  Just have 1 jQuery include - they're all the same version anyway.  Make sure the tablesorter include comes *after* the jQuery include.

Comment: for the example I did make them the same version, but for other things the rest of the team is using version 1.     if I remove the jquery from the table,  and just leave the one at the bottom I get SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined =(

Comment: Yes that's exactly what should happen.  Like I said earlier, make sure the tablesorter include comes *after* the jQuery include.

Comment: did. I put the script with jquery 3.2.1 outside the table at the bottom, and right after the tablesorter.  and I get       '$' is undefined   on the $(document).ready(function(){ line... I think didn't loaded the jquery, and that they only one that I have on now.   but if I move the <script> that hold the tablesorter after invoking the jquery and scr tablesorter does work,  I tought you could have everything anywhere since was on document ready, meaning will load everything first and then will run the functions

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery.noConflict, you can make multiple versions of jQuery coexist on the same page.  For instance

```
<script src='jquery-1.3.2.js'></script>
<script>
var jq132 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src='jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script>
var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: Not relevant - they're all the same version in the code in the question, despite OP asking how you deal with different versions.